# as3 unload from child

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to unload a ProLoader from the child.

Code in main.swf

```
import fl.display.ProLoader;
var myProLoader:ProLoader=new ProLoader();

page2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, page2content);
function page2content(e:MouseEvent):void {
var myURL:URLRequest=new URLRequest("page2.swf");
myProLoader.load(myURL);
addChild(myProLoader);
}


function unloadcontent(e:MouseEvent):void {
myProLoader.unload();
}
```

Code in page2.swf:

```
return_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,back);

function back(e:MouseEvent):void{
parent.parent['unloadcontent']();
}
```

When I run these, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on _09Start_working_fla::MainTimeline/unloadcontent(). Expected 1, got 0. at page2_fla::MainTimeline/back()
```

I just want the mc in child.swf to unload the content of the ProLoader(back to main).

Thanks for help.

Regards,
Reidar Nygård

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unloadcontent function expects an argument of type MouseEvent. In order to call it without having to pass one in, change it to:

```
function unloadcontent(e:MouseEvent = null):void
```